# Disabled QGraphicsItem prevents scrolling of QGraphicsView

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem

I have multiple `QGraphicsItems` with the `ItemIsSelectable`, `ItemIsMovable` and `ItemSendsGeometryChanges` flags.

Sometimes I want to disable selection and movement of those items, and I'm currently doing this by calling `QGraphicsItem.setEnabled(False)`. However, when the cursor is on top of a disabled `QGraphicsItem`, the scroll wheel doesn't scroll the view anymore. I have tried to find a solution through Google, but I haven't found any working solutions.

So, my question is: Is there an easy way to *not* make disabled items prevent scrolling if the cursor is hovering over them?

If not, I can just write an own function that disables the mentioned flags instead of calling `setEnabled()` on the `QGraphicsItem`, but I'm still wondering why scrolling doesn't work, and if I really can't let disabled items ignore the scrolling event.

One thing I've tried already, is disabling `Qt.MiddleButton` with a `setAcceptedMouseButtons()` call, but that didn't seem to change anything.

My setup: Windows 7, Python 2.7.3 and PyQt4

Comment: You might be able adapt the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34476962/1994235

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[void QGraphicsItem::setEnabled(bool enabled)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#setEnabled)

> Disabled items are visible, but they do not receive any events
>   Mouse events are discarded

That is the explanation why your mouse events - scroll wheel - are not working.
And why trying to change designation of mouse buttons doesn't make a difference - the item simply doesn't care :-)

If you want to disable movement and selection of a `QGraphicsItem`, the best way is to unset their `QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable` and `QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable` flags.

This really seems simpler... As you probably already noticed.

The alternative - as the linked answer shows - is to install a scene event filter, have other items filter the disabled items events.   The following question has good info:

[Event filter on QGraphicsItem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3239504/1217150)

Comment: Yes, unsetting those flags is what I decided to do in the end.